# ORA-01476: Divisor is equal to zero

Tags: sql

I have this query that I've been given to fix and I cannot understand why its causing error. I reviewed similar topics involving the max function and the null function but I can't seem to make them work without throwing another error.

```
select case when count(trlr_num) > 0 then 'Inbounds Need Closed'
             else 'All Good'
        end as "Inbounds To Be Closed"
   from (select t.trlr_num,
                r.invnum "Invoice",
                to_char(nvl(max(rl.init_rcv_dte), sysdate), 'MM/DD/YY HH:MI AM') as "Begin receive date",
                round(sum(rl.idnqty) / sum(rl.expqty) *100, 1) as "% Received%"
           from trlr t
           join rcvinv r
             on t.trlr_num = r.trknum
           join rcvlin rl
             on r.trknum = rl.trknum
            and r.supnum = rl.supnum
            and r.invnum = rl.invnum
            and r.wh_id = rl.wh_id
           join rcvtrk rt
             on r.trknum = rt.trknum
            and t.trlr_id = rt.trlr_id
            and r.wh_id = rt.wh_id
          where t.yard_loc_wh_id = 'US_3218'
            and rt.rcvtrk_stat <> 'C'
            and r.invtyp not in ('PKG', 'XFR')
            and (rl.rcvsts <> 'QI' or (rl.rcvsts = 'QI' and t.trlr_seal1 is not null and t.trlr_seal2 is not null))
          group by t.trlr_num,
                r.invnum
         having sum(rl.idnqty) / sum(rl.expqty) = 1
            and nvl(max(rl.init_rcv_dte), sysdate) < sysdate -2)
```

Comment: Hi - what don’t you understand about the error message? It seems to be stating very clearly what the problem is

Comment: you get sum(rl.expqty) = 0

Comment: Sorry NickW, what I don't understand is how to fix the error. Still very new into SQL and no training to turn to.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Use `nvl(sum(rl.expqty), 0)` to avoid the divide by zero. I see two places that need to be fixed.

Comment: It's telling you that in at least one of your groups the sum of expqty is zero.  Go look at your data, select t.trl_num, r.invnum and rl.expqty and find where it is zero or missing.  That will give you a hint what to do.  We can't help without seeing more.

Comment: You can use nvl(sum(rl.expqty), 1), not nvl(sum(rl.expqty), 0) given in one of the other comments. That will stop the error but may not give the result you want - only you can know what the end result should be if the sum equates to zero